# Iterating through Table View Cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know that there are many questions out there like this, but I have tried their solutions and have not gotten anything to work, so please hear me out.

I have a view controller called `MainTableViewController` , and a table view cell type called `MainTableViewCell`. I am using a switch that, when on, I want a label of the cell to be displayed. I know how to setup the switch, the function, and how to toggle the label. The only part I don't understand is looping through all the cells.

I have tried: in the main "tableview" function, adding each cell to an array (for some reason they do not stay in the array), and looping through each of the MainTableView.visibleCells(), but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate anything. Simply reload the table view when the switch changes. Then make sure the implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` sets up each cell appropriately for the current state of the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mutable array to represent the state of each label in each cell.  It should not hold a reference to the cells themselves.   Whenever the switch state changes , update the array, then send the table view a reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: You can loop thru the entire array or employ some logic that updates just the affected cells.

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method , change the state of the label accordingly.

Comment: This is still giving me an error, but on a line that works fine otherwise. If I remove that line, the error just appears o the next line...

Comment: In View Did Load, my table view is not nil, but in the delegate function it suddenly is! That is the error... Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a UILabel disappear on the toggle of a switch statement, you have to reload the cells.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

If the data you currently see in your cells is all static and typed in manually for different cell indexPath.rows through a switch, then you are not using the table view's main delegate method, cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

You must put the switch in this delegate method on the indexPath.row because it is this method that gets called repeatedly when new cells appear from, say, the bottom and then disappear when they leave from the top to be reused and rebuilt using the same delegate method.

Put the switch in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: When I call tableView.reloadData(), or in my case `MainTableView.reloadData()`, it gives me an error that Main Table View is nil. However, when I test it in View Did Load, it is not nil. Why is it nil inside of the delegate function?

Comment: Is MainTableView a class? Call tableView

Comment: MainTableViewController is the name of my class, and MainTableView is my Outlet

Comment: Read every character in the table view delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath: including the variables and you will see that the variable name to access your table view is called tableView. Use that when you do .reloadData().

Comment: I tried that, but I kept on getting errors on lines inside of view did load that I never got before. When I remove the first line the error appears on, it moves down to the next line. What is going on?

Comment: When you do tableView.reloadData(), what is the exact error that you get?

Comment: Exc Bad Instruction error, in the console: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. It happens on the line where I am setting the title for a bar button item, and if I remove that line it moves on to the line below where I define its target and action

Comment: You have to add ! at the end of .titleLabel in every place you use it, so it'll read .titleLabel!.text or .titleLabel!.target, etc.

Comment: Look for the little buttons in the red error markers and in cases like these you can fix it by clicking them all

Comment: There are no error markers in the code, but when I run it these lines give me trouble: `settings!.title = NSString(string: "\u{2699}\u{0000FE0E}") as String!
        let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(25);
        settings!.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        settings!.target = self.revealViewController()
        settings!.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))` (Settings is a bar button item)

Comment: Don't use NSString in Swift anymore. Just use String and type it like settings!.title = "\u{2699}\u{0000FE0E}"

Comment: Also I thought we were talking about a label. A bar button label?

Comment: Yes, a bar button and its attributes is what brings the error. It seems to be nil after a switch is pressed inside another view controller, so maybe there is something that is not connected with my delegate?